# Maximum number of linearly independent eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Is there an upper bound on the number of linearly independent eigenvectors of any matrix  ?

At best how many independent eigenvectors can a matrix have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an $n \times n$ matrix with coefficients in a field $\mathbb{K}$, you can have at most $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. An eigenvector being an element of $\mathbb{K}^n$, you cannot have more than $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Conversely, you can easily construct a matrix which has exactly $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors : the identity $I_n$.

Comment: Thank you, such maximum number of linearly independent eigenvectors also span the space, right?

Comment: Yes, because in a vector space of dimension $n$, a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors always span the space.